# Detecting and writing when client side disconnects

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server, disconnect

im writing a simple Client/Server application in C#.
as you see there is if(cSocket.Connected) tag in the codes, i want something like that...
if a cSocket disconnected...
i will give the codes, you can understand my problem from the title and my explanation...

Here is the code;

Server;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpListener sSocket = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 3162);
        int Counter = 0;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine("\n >> Server Started!");
        sSocket.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            Socket cSocket = sSocket.AcceptSocket();
            NetworkStream NetworkStr = new NetworkStream(cSocket);
            BinaryReader bReader = new BinaryReader(NetworkStr);
            BinaryWriter bWriter = new BinaryWriter(NetworkStr);
            IPEndPoint remoteIpEndPoint = cSocket.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint;

            if (cSocket.Connected)
            {
                Counter = Counter + 1;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.WriteLine("\n >> Client Connected! ~ Total: " + Counter + " ~ [" + remoteIpEndPoint + "]");
                bWriter.Write("\n >> Server Says: You Connected to Me!");
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Thanks for your helps :)

Comment: What do you mean by **Connected**?? You can only initial NetworkStream from a connected socket.(I mean it is already connected socket when AcceptSocket returns)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that familiar with .NET things but in theory applications and protocols (including TCP/IP) have some kind of timeout to wait for. Like in the TCP/IP protocol family one side waits for the another for a certain amount of time after sending a package and if he doesn't get an answer he tries again and/or closes the connection after some time.

In short you can send a small request periodically and check if the client answers.

Answer (score 0):

As Opi saied something like this will do it(It is from another Answer in StackOverFlow):

```
 public static bool SocketConnected(Socket s)
        {
            if (!s.Connected) return false;
            bool part1 = s.Poll(1000, SelectMode.SelectRead);
            bool part2 = (s.Available == 0);
            if (part1 & part2)
                return false;
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: i mean in vb there is winsock control and it has "close" event, but there is no event like that in c#, i will use your code :) thanks for your helps...